# How to set an alarm for a selected date and time?

Tags: java, android

I have this code from where I can set a time and date from date picker and time picker at once:

```
 private void dialoguetime() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogue);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setTitle("This is Dialog 1");
    dialog.show();

    TimePicker time_picker = (TimePicker) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    hours = time_picker.getCurrentHour();
    minute = time_picker.getCurrentMinute();
    time_picker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                int minutes) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(CustomDialog.this,
            // "hourOfDay = "+hourOfDay+"minute = "+minute , 1000).show();
            hours = hourOfDay;
            minute = minutes;
        }
    });

    final DatePicker date_picker = (DatePicker) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            xDate = date_picker.getYear() + "-"+ (date_picker.getMonth() + 1) + "-"+ date_picker.getDayOfMonth() + " " + hours+ ":" + minute + ":00";
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    xDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }

    }

    );

}
```

From this I can get a string as a date format like this `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, now I want to give an alert (as alarm) to the user of that selected time. I have used alarm manager for this but it didn't allow me to select that date?

How can I do this?

Comment: Post your alarm manager code, please.

Comment: I am a begineer about alerm manager, the alarm manager I used was in another project and it was sending a sms after every 15 minutes, but I know that wont work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the API for AlarmManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) you can see that the method

```
set()
```

requires the following parameters:

```
public void set (int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

where

```
int type = One of ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC or RTC_WAKEUP.
long triggerAtMillis = time in milliseconds that the alarm should go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).
PendingIntent operation = Action to perform when the alarm goes off
```

So basicly what you should do, is to get the time between the selected date (DateFormat.parse() to parse the date-formated string to date) and the current date. Something like this:

```
Date now = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = format.parse(YOUR_PICKED_DATE_AS_STRING);
long alertTime = parsedDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

Intent someIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClass.class);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, someIntent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.set(AlarmManager.
```